# Add custom language - localization

Tags: android

Im using localization in my Android app. I change the localization inside the app, so it doesn't change the system settings. I create dirs with the name "values-nl" and "values-en". This works fine. Buts lets say I want to create my own language. When I do this and create my own folder like "values-test" is trows me an error.

this is how i set the localization inside the app:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("nl");   
Locale.setDefault(locale);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Buts lets say I want to create my own language.

This is not possible, except via custom firmware. `-test` is not going to be a recognized resource set. You are welcome to support any of the languages that your desired version of Android supports -- you can find the list of these in the Locales section of the SDK release notes, such as [these for Android 4.0.3](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-4.0.3.html#locs).

Reputedly, you can use `Locale` to change what resource set will be used on the fly, though I have not tried this myself.

Comment: okey. But actually is a dialect of a language. I've read something about languages en regions. Isn't there any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: @Melvin: I do not care if you think you are inventing a new language, a new dialect, a new screen size, a new orientation, or whatever -- you cannot invent new resource set suffixes, except via custom firmware.